# Apache is not rereading my PHP file

Tags: php, apache, file, freebsd

I have a PHP file for a small jobe. I do update it frequently depending on the problems I face. Now Apache or PHP is using an old version of it. I have update it several times via ftp but the output on my browser shows that it is an old version. Why is that?

As if it has cached it.

Apache 2.2.20 on FreeBSD. PHP 5.3.8

Comment: CTRL+F5 to force refresh on your browser and verify you are saving it in the right folder

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364, it is in the right folder.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the old file, see if you can still load it. If yes reboot the apache server if that is not possible wait a few and try to disable caching or rename the file :) We can't clearly see what is exactly your problem, maybe it's an error, maybe configuration, maybe stupid caching. Add your config files if you would like a clear answer to the why :)